# Review team sandbox account

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, review

Review team rejected the second version of my app ( they approved the first version ). In screenshots they provided i can see, that they use sandbox account.

But i've got server-side validation, so release builds validate in-apps on `"buy apple com"`, not on `"sandbox apple com"`.

Should i make exception for their test account, or is it kind of mistake? Did anyone face this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer was in TN2259. For server-side validation you should validate receipt first on production server, than, if 21007 code returned, on sandbox server. *((